# Generate dump with unmanaged code crash?

Tags: .net, debugging, dump

Is there a way that I can get a full crash dump when my application crashes suddenly?

The problem is that I suspect that it's due to unmanaged code that kills the .net framework itself, and because of that, unless there's a debugger attached to the application at the moment of the crash, the application doesn't even gets a chance to handle the crash.

I can't attach a debugger and wait, because the crash happens randomly and we have many installed locations, so I'm wondering if it's possible to do this without attaching a debugger.

Edit: I'm aware of Microsoft Debugging SDK, and I also just found out about DebugDiag. I'd like to do this without having to attach to the application each time, as it's usually in the middle of a sale and I don't have time to attach the debugger and explore the stack trace. DebugDiag does seem to let me setup a rule for this, but it seems to only work on already running processes, rather than waiting for some process to launch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [adplus -crash](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/286350) or [userdump.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241215).

Answer (score 0):

debugdiag is fully [scriptable](http://blogs.iis.net/sukesh/archive/2006/06/02/ddintro.aspx). When I was having problems like this, we would have it scan for certain process names, and attach automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to edit the registry so that when crashes occur it invokes the appropriate application to generate the dump. So in your case I would get Dr. Watson to generate the crash dump.

See [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/15/capturing-application-crash-dumps.aspx)

Basically edit the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug`

set values

```
Value Name = Auto
Type = String (REG_SZ)
Data Value = 1 or 0. (Default is 1)
Value Name = Debugger
Type = String (REG_SZ)
Data Value = drwtsn32 -p %ld -e %ld -g
```

This will invoke Dr. Watson at the point that your app crashes. See the link in this post for further details, note that you will need to set the Auto value to 0 if you want to not have Dr. Watson be invoked in future.

Answer (score 0):

Create a General exception handler for your program. Inside the exception handler write a code to manually create a dump in the desired path.

This Link would help
http://brakertech.com/howto-c-generate-dump-file-on-crash/