# How do I automate mini dump creation when a c++ assertion fails?

Tags: c++, .net, debugging, windbg, assertions

I am using Sqlite on a production server but getting into deadlock scenarios.  I compiled the System.Data.Sqlite.org dll in debug mode and the deadlocks went away (Of course they did..)

Now, since we are compiled in debug mode, every once and a while I am getting assertion failures.. These apparently just come up as a dialog and don't get logged anywhere?

Is there a way, possibly with DebugDiag or another tool, to create a memory dump when the assertion failure happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MiniDumpWriteDump: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and set the appropriate flags to enable all the relevant information to be written into the dump.

It is possible for you to tell Windows to do this for you by setting a registry key and there is adplus and procdump, see related question: [crash generate dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073135/crash-generate-dump) and this: [Generate dump with unmanaged code crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265171/generate-dump-with-unmanaged-code-crash)

Answer (score 2):

Create DebugDiag crash rule for your application, add breakpoint with the expression

```
MSVCR90D!_wassert
```

to catch plain assert macro defined in cassert and

```
MSVCR90D!_CrtDbgReport
```

to catch Microsoft debug CRT _ASSERT, _ASSERTE macros,

```
MSVCR90D!_CrtDbgReportW
```

if you are compiling with unicode enabled.

You can find out the needed expression by adding breakpoint for Ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess, pressing abort in assertion failure dialog and looking at stack trace in the generated log (c:\Program Files\DebugDiag\Logs\<process name>).

To get rid of "Abort, Retry or Ignore" dialog call

```
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
```

somewhere at the application startup (see [the detailed _CrtSetReportMode description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y71x448%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN). Unfortunately this works for _ASSERT, _ASSERTE macros only, the _wassert function skips these _Crt mode settings and custom hooks completely.

*Notes:*

1. MSVCR90D is the library name for CRT that comes with Visual Studio 2008 (for VS2010 it will be MSVCR100D).
2. You should run the application directly (from Explorer or "Start Without Debugging" from Visual Studio) for DebugDiag to have a change to attach to it.

Comment: None of these rules appear to be working.  I set all the rules above and I am not getting any dumps.

I also set the report mode to _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG and am still getting dialogs.. perhaps because its not using _ASSERT..

I am calling assert(0) for my test.  I am not 100% sure where this is defined, I am a total newb when it comes to c.  When I hit go to definition in VS, it takes me to assert.h. The code is compiled with vs 2008 in debug mode, compiled as c code.

Comment: So, apparently when I hit go to definition on assert it takes me to c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SmartDevices\SDK\PocketPC2003\Include\assert.h

Comment: @AlexSpence I've expanded the answer. Maybe you were running the application from within Visual Studio which attaches its own debugger, try "Start Without Debugging" option and see in DebugDiag logs if it successfully attached (View - Logs Folder). Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I was running it through the visual studio console app host, that was most likely the problem.  I was finally able to get a dump created with a combination of MiniDumpWriteDump and _CrtSetReportHook2.  Thanks alot!